# error on updating grid view values asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have usedgridView for update and delete data. But I'm getting

"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index" error while updating.

Comment: post full aspx of grid...i am not able to see your edit button in grid

Comment: @ÁngelDiMaría : Please check now

Comment: have you debug your code?in which line it gives this error?

Comment: check the value if `Date_Borrowed` and `Date_Returned`. What is data type of those column in database table?

Comment: @yogi970 : im getting error on this line " int Copy_Id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[1]);"

Comment: @Imad: its defined as "Date" type

Comment: @mahimachand: Ur question title is misleading ma'am.

Comment: @Imad : i corrected it imad

Comment: select `GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[1]` and add it to watch to see what value its giving.

Comment: why you have removed all code from this question ? is your problem resolved?

Comment: @yogi970 L no still not. im still getting errors :(

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in your jquery datetimepicker

Problem seems to be in :

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
```

Simply take separate link buttons for edit and delete as:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ItemStyle-Width="150">
     <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:linkbutton id="lnkEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-Width="150">
     <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:linkbutton id="lnkDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are using dropdownlist for copy_id so it is better to use the below code to find the dropdownlist and fetch value from it.

```
 DropDownList lblCopyDdl= (DropDownList )GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblCopyId");
 int Copy_Id = Convert.ToInt32(lblCopyDdl.selectedvalue);
```

> Recommendation::
>   Better if you use the same code as mentioned above for other fields for getting value..
>
> for eg

```
int Borrower_Id = Convert.ToInt32((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBorrowerId").Text);
```

#### Update::

If it not works then do check your e.RowIndex as mentioned in Ángel Di María's answer.

#### Update 2

try to fetch the date field like this

```
 DateTime Date_Borrowed = Convert.ToDateTime((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDateBorrowed").Text);
```

and

```
 DateTime Date_Returned= Convert.ToDateTime((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDateReturned").Text);
```

Comment: i have done the changes on above mentioned fields. Now im getting same error whic got previously for "          DateTime Date_Borrowed = Convert.ToDateTime(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[2]) ;
           DateTime Date_Returned = Convert.ToDateTime(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[3]);" lines

Comment: now you are not getting error on copy_id field? if no then change code for other field also as i mentioned in "Recommendation"!

Comment: Oh you are using date picker.Try to make txtDateReturned as "ReadOnly". If it works then do comment here

Comment: im geeting error for ".Text"  [web.UI.Control does not contain definition for 'Text']

Comment: is this error in  "txtDateReturned" textbox only,other then this all other textboxes and dropdown giving values properly?

also check your "txtDateReturned" in source. i think you have miss spell the Test property to "sText". just check it

Comment: yesi changed the sText field. but still getting error

Comment: as i told you try to check that are you getting any date in the date textboxes after button click? and you haven't reply for my last comment's first part.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to read  a cell value using index but there is no data element at that position. Suggest you to do debug and increment index value in your collection in watch window and observe data